# Building a MSI installer that auto registers DLL file in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, dll

I have been working on an old tool that was written in VB for ArcMap that uses COM's that call to EsriRegAsm to register the dll file for ArcMap to use.  I was tasked to make the process a little easier to install this tool because the user base would not have admin rights any longer to use the CMD prompt.
I took to do this by either

1. making it a Esriaddin which would have been too time consuming or
2. using a MSI installer, for time sake it seemed the MSI installer was the way to go since I found an [article](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000006209) that detailed what I thought was an auto registration vb script from ESRI.  I am guessing I either missed something in the process or didn't add it the installer where it needed to be located for it to register upon install of the DLL files.

I have provided the code that I have placed into my vbproject using Visual Studio 2019, but it is pretty much a direct copy from the article linked above.  I have used the MSI extension from Visual Studio 2019 to create the installation package

I have looked on GIS Stack Exchange so I am just trying to see if I have missed something, since I have not been able to get this to work as I thought it was suppose too.  I should clarify that the MSI does install the dll files needed and the tool will work but it does not register the file upon install.

I have ended up just creating .bat files that install with the MSI installer and that the user would need to double click on, but without admin rights the user will need to have some type of auto registration eventually.

I am looking for a little direction into if I am miss understanding this article and if anyone has had a similar issue ?
I should note that I followed the articles instructions to the "T" but I am worried that I was supposed to add the installer class to some place in the project that was not made specifically clear..

```
    Imports System.ComponentModel
    Imports System.Configuration.Install
    Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class COMinstaller

    'this is the installer for the COM files that the LegalSearch dll file uses.  I have written the Vb script just as the instructions have
    'stated but it doesn't seem to acknowledge the state of the system files, even though the saveState file is clearly created by the stateSaver
    'I have created a work around, where the actual installation file has two text files for Registristering and de-registratering the dll file.
    'this link to the instructions on creating this COM Script is https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000006209
    Public Overrides Sub Install(ByVal stateSaver As System.Collections.IDictionary)
        Try
            MyBase.Install(stateSaver)
            Dim regsrv As New RegistrationServices()
            If Not (regsrv.RegisterAssembly(MyBase.GetType().Assembly, AssemblyRegistrationFlags.SetCodeBase)) Then
                Throw New InstallException("Failed To Register for COM")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error during installation")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub Uninstall(ByVal savedState As System.Collections.IDictionary)
        Try
            MyBase.Uninstall(savedState)
            Dim regsrv As New RegistrationServices()
            If Not (regsrv.UnregisterAssembly(MyBase.GetType().Assembly)) Then
                Throw New InstallException("Failed To Unregister for COM")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error during uninstallation")
        End Try
        'Add initialization code after the call to InitializeComponent

    End Sub

End Class
```

Below is the image of the custom action for the install and uninstall
[image]

Comment: Friendly request to make your question more readable. E.g. use shorter sentences, break text up in paragraphs, add interpunction, ...

Comment: Berend,  thanks I have made a few edits as you have requested let me know if that is better or not...

Comment: How are you creating the msi? The code in the installer class you added must be executed somehow. In the past, I have used the Microsoft Visual Studio Installer extension myself, this allows for custom (un)installer actions to be defined (step 7–10 in the article you linked to)

Comment: sorry for not clarifying, I am using the Visual Studio 2019 installer extension as well.  I just added the new installer class, that contains the code above, to my project as this instructions said and compiled the build for the dll and the MSI installer.  The instructions also mention creating custom actions for the installer but did not mention placing the said above code in those actions.

Comment: They do. As I said, step 7-10

Comment: Berend, oh okay let me look through the documentation again and see if I can figure out what I missed.

Comment: I went through that and it did not result in the installer class registering the dll.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom action needs to result in a call to ESRIRegAsm.exe for each .dll.  I followed this document... I have 50+ ArcObject dll's deployed on ~150 workstations.

[Building a MSI installer that auto registers DLL file in ArcMap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/445206/building-a-msi-installer-that-auto-registers-dll-file-in-arcmap)

Comment: Sherry, 
That is good to know but could you explain what you did specifically in your custom action that allows it to call to the ESRIRegAsm.exe that I am missing?

Comment: Popboarder, I apologize for not checking the link I provided.  What it boils down to is you need to create a new class for calling ESRIRegAsm.exe.  For each .dll, your custom action will run this new class passing in your custom.dll name as a parameter.

https://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/How_to_deploy_a_custom_component_using_a_setup_project/00010000016r000000/

Comment: Sherry,
sorry for the late response, thank you for the information and clarity the link you provided helped to clear up what I was missing in my installer, thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Sherry's answer with the link for the help documentation helped me figure out my issue.

"Popboarder, I apologize for not checking the link I provided. What it boils down to is you need to create a new class for calling ESRIRegAsm.exe. For each .dll, your custom action will run this new class passing in your custom.dll name as a parameter. help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/… –
Sherry
Dec 5, 2022 at 17:17"